# Finding the largest palindrome product of two 3-digit numbers: what is the error in logic?

Tags: python, algorithm, palindrome

I thought of solving this problem in the following way: start with two variables with value 999, multiplying one by another in a loop that decrements one or the other until a palindrome is found. The code is this:

```
def is_palindrome(n):
  if str(n) == str(n)[::-1]:
    return True
  else:
    return False

def largest_palindrome_product_of_3_digit():
  x = 999
  y = 999
  for i in reversed(range(x + y + 1)):
    if is_palindrome(x * y):
      return x * y
    if i % 2 == 0:
      x -= 1
    else:
      y -= 1
```

The result of my method is 698896, while the correct result is 906609. Could you point me where my logic is incorrect?

Comment: If you always decrement x and y alternatively, won't x and y always be very close together? What if the numbers you're looking for are more than one apart?

Comment: You have to scan all the possible combinations of 3-digit numbers, so you should use two nested for cycles, one that increments x and one that increments y, both from 100 to 999.

Comment: My thought was that the first palindrome product of two numbers close together at the high end of the range would be higher than the palindrome products found before. I'm wrong, but I don't know why. 698896, the wrong result of my method, is the result of 836 * 836. How could there be higher palindrome products when I'm decrementing one by one from the high end of the range?

Comment: x and y are never more than 1 apart. You don't cover cases like 999*997, which is obviously much greater than 836*836.

Comment: Oh, I think I got it now. Thanks @Rawing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of hints:

1. If n=y*x is *any* number in the range(600000, 700000) (for example) with y<=x, and x<1000, what's the smallest possible value of x?
2. If n is a *palindromic* number, both its first and last digit are 6, so what does that imply about the last digits of x & y?

Now generalize and figure out an efficient algorithm. :)

I've never done this problem before, but I just coded a reasonably fast algorithm that's around 2000 times faster than a brute-force search that uses

```
for x in xrange(2, 1000): 
    for y in xrange(2, x+1):
        n = y*x
        #etc
```

According to timeit.py, the brute-force algorithm takes around 1.29 seconds on my old machine, the algorithm I hinted at above takes around 747 microseconds.

---

**Edit**

I've improved my bounds (and modified my algorithm slightly) and brought the time down to 410 µsec. :)

To answer your questions in the comment:

Yes, we can start x at the square root of the beginning of the range, and we can stop y at x (just in case we find a palindromic square).

What I was getting at with my 2nd hint is that for x=10*I+i, y=10*J+j, we don't need to test all 81 combinations of i and j, we only need to test the ones where (i*j)%10 equals the digit we want. So if we know that our palindrome starts and ends with 9 then (i, j) must be in [(1, 9), (3, 3), (7, 7), (9, 1)].

I don't think I should post my actual code here; it's considered bad form on SO to post complete solutions to Project Euler problems. And perhaps some SO people don't even like it when people supply hints. Maybe that's why I got down-voted...

Comment: Is the smallest possible value of x is the square root of the beginning of the range? And there is no need to test for y < (end of the range) / 999? I don't know what it implies for the last digits of x and y that both the first and last digit of their product are the same. I'm curious to see your algorithm. Thanks for your time! (I wasn't the one who downvoted you btw).

Comment: Nice! Thank you sir, I should be able to code it now.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing possible numbers.

You're considering O(x+y) numbers and you need to consider O(x * y) numbers. Your choices are, essentially, to either loop one of them from 999, down to 1, then decrement the other and...

Simple demonstration:

```
>>> want = set()
>>> for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
...   for y in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
...     want.add(x * y)
... 
>>> got = set()
>>> x = 5
>>> y = 5
>>> for i in reversed(range(x + y + 1)):
...   got.add(x * y)
...   if i % 2:
...     x -= 1
...   else:
...     y -= 1
... 
>>> want == got
False
```

Alternatively, you do know the top of the range (999 * 999) and you can generate all palindromic numbers in that range, from the highest to the lowest. From there, doing a prime factorization and checking if there's a split of the factors that multiply to two numbers in the range [100,999] is trivial.